# Make knockout observablearray items observable with ko.mapping

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have this model :

```
var child = function(c){
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(c.id);
    self.first_name = ko.observable(c.first_name);
    self.last_name = ko.observable(c.last_name);
    self.gender_id = ko.observable(c.gender_id);
    self.birthday= ko.observable(c.birthday);
    self.family_id = ko.observable(c.family_id);
}
```

And i have a viewmodel defined like this:

```
var childrenViewModel = function(initialData){
    var self = this;
    //
    self.children = ko.observableArray(initialData);
    //
    self.removeChild = function(){};
};
```

I am fetching initially data in this way:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: getChildrenListUrl,
    contentType: 'application/json'
})
    .done(function (data) {
        vmChildren =new childrenViewModel(JSON.parse(data));
        ko.applyBindings(vmChildren,document.getElementById('portlet-children'));
        Metronic.unblockUI('#portlet-children');
    });
```

I now want to make the contents of the children observablearray, observables themselves by using mapping plugin and i am having difficulties in doing so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need `ko.mapping`, dont you just want to map `initialData` to be instances of `child`?

```
self.children = ko.observableArray(initialData.map(function(e){ 
                                         return new child(e);
                                   }));
```

See [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I suppose that my lack of standard javascript knowledge stopped me from finding this in the first place, yes? I thought that by using mapping was the only way around this..Thanks

Comment: @e4rthdog - your edit got rejected - but it was 100% right so I put it in. My bad, sorry.